# Cannot click on button: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a 'submit order' button from a menu that appears after 'preview' is clicked on this page: https://www.investopedia.com/simulator/trade/stocks. However, I cannot click it.

Trying to fix it, I read in some places to try using JS click as a last resort. However, i still get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="/simulator/portfolio" class="v-tab text-h6 white--text px-8" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false" role="tab" data-cy="global-nav-item">...</a> is not clickable at point (179, 24). Other element would receive the click: <div class="v-overlay__scrim" style="opacity: 0.46; background-color: rgb(33, 33, 33); border-color: rgb(33, 33, 33);"></div>
  (Session info: chrome=122.0.6261.129)
```

This is my code:

```
elem = self.browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "semi-bold.v-btn.v-btn--has-bg.v-btn--tile.theme--light.elevation-0.v-size--default.primary")
            print(elem.get_attribute('outerHTML')) #trying to print the element to see if it is correct
            self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
```

This is the button I am trying to click:

```
<button data-v-1710ba40="" data-v-44e4901d="" type="button" class="semi-bold v-btn v-btn--has-bg v-btn--tile theme--light elevation-0 v-size--default primary" role="button" aria-label="" title="" data-cy="submit-order-button" style="height: 3rem; width: 100%;"><span class="v-btn__content">
              Submit Order
              <span data-v-44e4901d="" aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate theme--light white--text"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img" aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon__svg"><path d="M8.59,16.58L13.17,12L8.59,7.41L10,6L16,12L10,18L8.59,16.58Z"></path></svg></span></span></button>
```

This is the related menu that the button appears on after 'preview' is clicked:

```
<div data-v-44e4901d="" class="v-card v-sheet theme--light"><button data-v-1710ba40="" data-v-94d6ba82="" data-v-44e4901d="" type="button" class="semi-bold float-right pa-5 v-btn v-btn--has-bg v-btn--tile theme--light elevation-0 v-size--default white" role="button" aria-label="" title="" data-cy="close-dialog-button" style="height: auto; width: auto;"><span class="v-btn__content"><span data-v-94d6ba82="" aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate text-right theme--light black--text"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img" aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon__svg"><path d="M19,6.41L17.59,5L12,10.59L6.41,5L5,6.41L10.59,12L5,17.59L6.41,19L12,13.41L17.59,19L19,17.59L13.41,12L19,6.41Z"></path></svg></span></span></button> <div data-v-44e4901d="" class="v-card__title headline">
      Preview Order
    </div> <div data-v-44e4901d="" class="v-card__text text--primary"><div data-v-44e4901d="" class="d-flex justify-center text-center mt-4"><div data-v-44e4901d="" class="mr-12"><p data-v-44e4901d="" data-cy="preview-order-type" class="text-subtitle-1 mb-0">
            Stock: Buy at Market
          </p> <p data-v-44e4901d="" data-cy="preview-stock-symbol" class="text-h5">
            NFLX
          </p></div> <div data-v-44e4901d=""><p data-v-44e4901d="" class="text-subtitle-1 mb-0">
            Quantity
          </p> <p data-v-44e4901d="" data-cy="preview-stock-quantity" class="text-h5">
            16
          </p></div></div> <div data-v-44e4901d=""><div data-v-44e4901d="" role="list" class="v-list preview-order-items v-sheet theme--light"><!----><div data-v-44e4901d="" tabindex="-1" data-cy="preview-list-item" role="listitem" class="v-list-item theme--light"><div data-v-44e4901d="" class="v-list-item__title text--primary">Duration</div> <div data-v-44e4901d="" class="v-list-item__subtitle text-subtitle-1 text--primary">Day Only</div></div><div data-v-44e4901d="" tabindex="-1" data-cy="preview-list-item" role="listitem" class="v-list-item theme--light"><div data-v-44e4901d="" class="v-list-item__title text--primary">Estimated Price</div> <div data-v-44e4901d="" class="v-list-item__subtitle text-subtitle-1 text--primary">$620.33</div></div><div data-v-44e4901d="" tabindex="-1" data-cy="preview-list-item" role="listitem" class="v-list-item theme--light"><div data-v-44e4901d="" class="v-list-item__title text--primary">Quantity</div> <div data-v-44e4901d="" class="v-list-item__subtitle text-subtitle-1 text--primary">16</div></div><div data-v-44e4901d="" tabindex="-1" data-cy="preview-list-item" role="listitem" class="v-list-item theme--light"><div data-v-44e4901d="" class="v-list-item__title text--primary">Commission</div> <div data-v-44e4901d="" class="v-list-item__subtitle text-subtitle-1 text--primary">$0.00</div></div><div data-v-44e4901d="" tabindex="-1" data-cy="preview-list-item" role="listitem" class="v-list-item theme--light"><div data-v-44e4901d="" class="v-list-item__title text--primary">Estimated Total</div> <div data-v-44e4901d="" class="v-list-item__subtitle text-subtitle-1 text--primary">$9,925.28</div></div></div></div></div> <div data-v-44e4901d="" class="v-card__actions justify-center"><div data-v-44e4901d="" class="container pa-0"><div data-v-44e4901d="" class="row"><div data-v-44e4901d="" class="col-12 col-sm-6 mb-4 order-sm-1 col order-2"><button data-v-1710ba40="" data-v-44e4901d="" type="button" class="semi-bold v-btn v-btn--outlined v-btn--tile theme--light elevation-0 v-size--default primary--text" role="button" aria-label="" title="" data-cy="change-order-button" style="height: 3rem; width: 100%;"><span class="v-btn__content">
              Change Order
            </span></button></div> <div data-v-44e4901d="" class="col-12 col-sm-6 mb-sm-4 order-sm-2 col order-1"><button data-v-1710ba40="" data-v-44e4901d="" type="button" class="semi-bold v-btn v-btn--has-bg v-btn--tile theme--light elevation-0 v-size--default primary" role="button" aria-label="" title="" data-cy="submit-order-button" style="height: 3rem; width: 100%;"><span class="v-btn__content">
              Submit Order
              <span data-v-44e4901d="" aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate theme--light white--text"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img" aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon__svg"><path d="M8.59,16.58L13.17,12L8.59,7.41L10,6L16,12L10,18L8.59,16.58Z"></path></svg></span></span></button></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: there's an overlay in front of the button at the time you are trying to click it.  Seems like that's probably something you just need to wait for (use a sleep), but if it's a dialog click the close button first.